# How to map the ListIem response values

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a question.
Right now i have API to get the listitem,
then render it.
But the response value is not explicit,
for example item.step_status value is S, RJ, F.
Question is I need to mapping it, for example S for Success, F for failed and RJ for Rejected.

subtitle={`Status: ${item.step_status}`} << This is the part that i need to update, right now value still either S, F and RJ need to mapping it like i mention above.

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              leftAvatar={{ title: item.step_status }}
              title={`${item.user_id} reason: ${item.leave_details}`}
              subtitle={`Status: ${item.step_status}`}
              onPress={() => {
                Alert.alert(
                  'Authorization for :',
                  `${item.user_id} reason: ${item.leave_details}`,
                  [
                    {
                      text: 'Cancel',
                      onPress: () => console.log('Cancel'),
                      style: 'cancel',
                    },
                    {
                      text: 'Reject',
                      onPress: () => this.dayoffProcess(item.id, 'RJ'),
                    },
                    {
                      text: 'Approve',
                      onPress: () => this.dayoffProcess(item.id, 'AP'),
                    },
                  ],
                  { cancelable: false },
                );
              }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        />
```

What is the simple way to mapping it?

Thanks before

Answer (score -1):

After reading some article,
i can solve it using ternary operator.

Below is the changes / sample :

```
  subtitle={
                <View>
                  {item.step_status == 'S' ? <Text>Status : Success</Text>
                    : item.step_status == 'AP' ? <Text>Status : Approved</Text>
                      : item.step_status == 'RJ' ? <Text>Status : Rejected</Text> : null}
                </View>
              }
```

Case closed.